# 301 Redirect all files within directory to directory root

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect all files within a directory to the directory root. So,

Original URLS:

```
http://www.mysite.com/about/whatsnew/2013DHReadersChoice.pdf

http://www.mysite.com/about/whatsnew_story.cfm?id=296

http://www.mysite.com/about/kitchen.cfm
```

All go to:

```
http://www.mysite.com/about/
```

All methods I've tried wind up in a loop.

Comment: .htaccess, along the lines of what anubhava supplied below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `RedireceMatch` in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(about)/.+$ /$1/
```

Comment: I have tested this, try it in a new browser to avoid caching issues.

Comment: Tried it. I also checked the redirect and it is redirecting /about/ to /about in a loop